# How to save automatically in hybris?

Tags: javascript, java, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to save the drop-down option on-selection in backoffice automatically without clicking the save button ( save button is disable)? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In a common case, when you need to implement such requirement for administration perspective for all item model, then I'd suggest you add event listener during editor UI rendering.

To do that, you need to implement custom section renderer:

```
public class CustomEditorAreaSectionRenderer extends com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer {

    @Autowired
    private ModelService modelService;

    @Override
    protected void processEditorBeforeComposition(final Editor editor, final DataType genericType, final WidgetInstanceManager widgetInstanceManager, final Attribute attribute, final Object object) {
        editor.addEventListener("onRequiredAction", (org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event event) -> {
            modelService.save(object);
        });
    }
}
```

Default implementation declared as a spring bean so you have an easy way to inject your custom implementation. For instance, via alias for `editorAreaSectionRenderer`. Default declaration looks like:

```
<alias name="defaultEditorAreaTabRenderer" alias="editorAreaTabRenderer"/>
<bean id="defaultEditorAreaTabRenderer"
      class="com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaTabRenderer"
      parent="abstractEditorAreaComponentRenderer" scope="prototype">
    <property name="editorAreaSectionRenderer" ref="editorAreaSectionRenderer"/>

</bean>

<alias name="defaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer" alias="editorAreaSectionRenderer"/>
<bean id="defaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer"
      class="com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.editorarea.renderer.impl.DefaultEditorAreaSectionRenderer"
      parent="abstractEditorAreaComponentRenderer" scope="prototype">
    <property name="editorAreaPanelRenderer" ref="editorAreaPanelRenderer"/>
    <property name="validationRenderer" ref="validationRenderer"/>

</bean>
```

Please be aware, that OOTB save process is a quite complex action and it should be executed with care. Take a look how it's implemented by default at `com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.baseeditorarea.DefaultEditorAreaController#saveObject`